# vscode format modified lines with eslint

Tags: visual-studio-code, vim, eslint, tslint

There are several developers working in my current project with different coding styles. Therefore, I need to configure my `vscode` with settings:

1. formatted only lines that were changed by me
2. formatting should run only when saving
3. possible to switch from `eslint` to `tslint`

My current config:

```
{
  "editor.formatOnPaste": false,
  "editor.formatOnType": false,
  "editor.formatOnSave": false,
  "editor.insertSpaces": true,
  "editor.defaultFormatter": "esbenp.prettier-vscode",
  "[typescript]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    }
  },
  "[javascript]": {
    "editor.codeActionsOnSave": {
      "source.fixAll.eslint": true
    }
  },
  "[json]": {
    "editor.formatOnSave": true
  },
}
```

Well, I would also hope to hear how developers solve a similar problem when working in `Vim` (because sometimes I use it). Thank you!

Comment: "There are several developers working in my current project with different coding styles." That is your problem and what your team should fix. Brittle technical workarounds are only making things worse.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The August 2020 update came with an option to "Only format modified"
https://code.visualstudio.com/updates/v1_49#_only-format-modified-text
That should cover 1. and 2. i belive.

If you want to format via `eslint --fix`, thats something that I'm looking for the answer to as well.
[only "eslint --fix" modified lines](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64205809/only-eslint-fix-modified-lines)

Comment: This doesn't actually appear to rectify the issue of the (in testing Prettier) formatter formatting not only the changed line(s), but the rest of the file from that point downwards.